# Russian Ruble exchange rate

Tags: finance, historical, programming, russia

I am looking for currency exchange data, specifically USDRUB and EURRUB quotes. I managed to find tick-by-tick data on the official site of the Moscow Exchange (MoEx). But I search data at a 15-30-minute timeframe.

Comment: Is there any way to do it using Oanda?

Answer (score 1):

This site will display and download exchange rates on a daily basis for the past year:

https://www.oanda.com/solutions-for-business/historical-rates-beta/

This OECD link will show you annual exchange rates (use custom option) back to 1995.

http://stats.oecd.org/index.aspx?queryid=169#

Comment: And what about 15-30-minute  data? There's nothing about it

Comment: I've not seen anything down to that resolution (15 min intervals) in a public dataset.